# Convert multiple columns into dict after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], "b":["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"], "c":[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1], "d":["x","y","z","x","y","y","z","x"]})


    a   b   c   d
0   1   a   0   x
1   1   a   0   y
2   1   a   1   z
3   2   b   0   x
4   2   b   1   y
5   2   b   1   y
6   3   c   0   z
7   3   c   1   x
```

I want to groupby on column a and column b to get following output:

```
    a   b   e
0   1   a   [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 0, 'd': 'y'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'z'}]
1   2   b   [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'y'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'y'}]
2   3   c   [{'c': 0, 'd': 'z'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'x'}]
```

My solution:

```
new_df = df.groupby(["a","b"])["c","d"].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient="records")).reset_index(name="e")
```

But issue is it is behaving inconsistently, sometimes I get below error:

> reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument "name"

It would be helpful if someone point out issue in above solution or provide an alternate way of doing.

Comment: Your code worked for me. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce, what is the output of `pd.__version__`?

Comment: @NYCCoder using pandas version 0.22 and solution works in most of the cases. It throws error in few cases even if the data is same. I have been scratching my head for weeks now and data seems to be ok for me

Comment: We have to see the data where it goes wrong to help. But what you can look at, only `Series.reset_index` has argument `name`. `DataFrame.reset_index` does not. So it probably goes wrong when there are more columns than `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: @Erfan initially I thought problem is with the data but after hours of debugging I could not find any inconsistency in the data.

Comment: The same code cannot go wrong in ceteris paribus, something must've changed, and I expect the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
new=ddf.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].apply(lambda x : x.to_dict('r')).to_frame('e').reset_index()
Out[13]: 
   a  b                                                  e
0  1  a  [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 0, 'd': 'y'}, {'c':...
1  2  b  [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'y'}, {'c':...
2  3  c           [{'c': 0, 'd': 'z'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'x'}]
```

Comment: How does this help OP's problem exactly?

Comment: We cannot know, because the original solution works on the test data set as well, this is just guessing.

Comment: @Erfan wait for the OP

Comment: getting an error `dataframe object has no attribute to_frame`

Comment: Exactly what I am saying, you have a `DataFrame` not a `Series`. Please read my comment carefully and it will solve your problem. @Sociopath

Comment: @Erfan thanks it was valuable info but real issue was I had few `np.nan` in column `b` which was causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we can do:

```
df['e'] = df[['c', 'd']].agg(lambda s: dict(zip(s.index, s.values)), axis=1)
df1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['e'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

---

```
# print(df1)
   a  b                                                  e
0  1  a  [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 0, 'd': 'y'}, {'c':...
1  2  b  [{'c': 0, 'd': 'x'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'y'}, {'c':...
2  3  c           [{'c': 0, 'd': 'z'}, {'c': 1, 'd': 'x'}]
```